# How to re-align objects with the array modifier

Tags: modifiers, empty

I'm following a tutorial on YouTube(https://youtu.be/3cjrRLbEtXo) where I'm supposed to create a gear-like structure on a castle.[image]
In following the tutorial, I'm supposed to apply an Empty, and then add an array modifier to a single gear so that as I link the object offset to the empty, rotate it, and increase the array count, it forms a circle/complete gear on its axis (starting from 00:32 - 00:43). [image]
[image]
But when I follow these steps in the tutorial, I get something entirely different. I don't know how to attach a video clip, so I'll just include the image below.[image]
The array counts form under the initial object. Not only do they form vertically (instead of horizontally to create a gear), they become twice the size of the previous count (please see the last image).

If you understand my plight or where I'm coming from, can you teach me how to correct it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Apply the transforms of your object and empty

Comment: @moonboots Thank you so much. I'm grateful. 

Comment: once you know how to create gears, you can also add the *Extra Objects* built-in blender addon to add gear meshes. can save you time. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/mesh_extra_objects.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the transforms of your object and empty (in *Object* mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)